# .NET Micro framework Compile and Deploy without VisualStudio

Tags: c#, .net-micro-framework

Firstly, thank you for bothering to look at my question as 5 days of Googling has left me dreary to say the least.

I would like to know of a way that I can compile and then deploy without the use of Visual Studio. I am able to compile and then use MetaDataProcessor.exe to generate my PE (Portable Executable) files with the -minimize option. However, this seems to be where I get a little stuck. I believe that I am supposed to generate a database file including all of the PE files referenced in my application, and from there I am supposed to convert this into a Motorola SRecord file, however when I take these steps I am getting this result:

1) My .hex file is somewhere around 3.5x larger than the .hex file I pull off of my board after using Visual Studio to deploy (65kb from VS and 305kb with my steps)

2) When attempting to deploy and run my .NETMF application, I receive an error from the board itself saying that at least one of my assemblies has a null checksum (it aborts after the first null checksum received)

What is the secret step that I am missing, or what step am I using incorrectly here? Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
James.

Comment: Try looking at uppercut, I am not sure if it will do everything you want but its what sprung to mind when I read your question: code.google.com/p/uppercut/

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response Andy, however, UppercuT seems to be an automated desktop deployment solution. I can however use this tool in other projects that I am working on, so I again thank you.